# Two custom cells with search bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to have two custom cells and search bar in my UIView Controller. at first I was able to do one cell and search bar and it was perfect then I added another cell and then everything became ugly.

Here is the idea of my custom cells
I get data from my server in JSON. Many shops, some of them have a design and some have no design. If a shop has a design I save the design in a variable as a string `withDesign`

```
                let shop_id = subJson["id"].stringValue
                var info = Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : designImage )
                 self.withDesign = self.shops.filter { $0.design != "" }
                 self.withOut =  self.shops.filter { $0.design == "" }
                 self.allShops = self.NofilteredArr + self.filteredArr
                print(self.filteredArr)
```

The first cell is called `design` and second is called `Cell`

[image]
[image]

[image]
I tried multiple ways but I failed because it's my first time to deal with two cells.

What I'm tryting to do is all shops will be listed in Cell and if there is a shop that has a design then make cells with the design if no design then just list the shops. Two separate customs cells

What I'm trying to do

[example of design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kbQU.png)

[example of cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhAMf.png)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: your code is not good please use if else condition properly

Comment: And that's why I asked here!

Comment: I give the example

Answer (score 1):

please Use code like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if searchActive
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry1 = auxiliar?[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: (entry1?.Logo)!))
        cell.shopName.text = entry1?.shopname
        return cell

    }else{
        if withDesign != nil
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

            let entry = withDesign[indexPath.row]

            cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
            cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
            return cell

        } else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "design", for: indexPath) as! DesignTableViewCell
            let entry = withDesign[indexPath.row]

            cell.deignImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.design))
            return cell

        }
    }
```

Comment: it gives fatal error: Index out of range  in `let entry = withDesign[indexPath.row]`

Comment: please debug the code and also check number of variable in  withDesign array

Comment: the number of withDesign is correct. What I'm tryting to do is all shops will be listed in `Cell` and if there is a shop that has a design then make cells with the design if no design then just list the shops. Two separate customscells

Comment: can you edit question with source code and fatal error screen shot

Comment: can you see my question again please

Comment: when you search the data using UISearchbar then you store data into filteredArr?

Comment: no I store data somewhere else. the search has no problem, displaying the design (if there is ) and list all the shops is my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154665/discussion-between-ios-singh-and-leo0019).